# Scp multiple files created in last one day from server to local fails

Tags: bash, unix, scp, xargs

I want to get multiple files that were generated in last 1 day, from server to local. I'm using the following command which says "No such file or directory".

`find username@server.xyz.com:/path-from-which-files-need-to-be-copied/ -type f -ctime -1 | xargs -ILIST scp LIST /Users/abcUser/Documents/test/`

**Error**
find: username@server.xyz.com:/path-from-which-files-need-to-be-copied/: No such file or directory

PS: I can access this location and scp from this location for single files with filenames.

Comment: The `find` utility looks at a **local** filesystem. It's not able to reach across an ssh connection (if that's what you intended) and make a list of files on a remote server. You might want to look at `rsync` as a better solution for this.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it.

Comment: In the mean time, since this question is based on a false premise and isn't really about programming, you may wish to delete it just to keep the SO question queue a little cleaner.

Comment: It is actually doable using find. My requirement specifically asks me for the last 1 days files. And i can't actually store all the files in local after processing. So rync won't work. Because rsync works only for the delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` can find only local files. So run `find` on remote server, something along:

```
ssh username@server.xyz.com find /path-from-which-files-need-to-be-copied/ -type f -ctime -1 |
xargs -ILIST scp username@server.xyz.com:LIST /Users/abcUser/Documents/test/
```

Note that `xargs` by default parses `\` and quotes in it's own way. The best way to pass the result of `find` is to use zero terminated stream:

```
ssh username@server.xyz.com find /path-from-which-files-need-to-be-copied/ -type f -ctime -1 -print0 |
xargs -0 -ILIST scp username@server.xyz.com:LIST /Users/abcUser/Documents/test/
```

But `xargs` will invoke separate `scp` session for each file, which will be very slow. So optimize it by running a single `scp` for all files, I think you could do it something like this:

```
ssh username@server.xyz.com find /path-from-which-files-need-to-be-copied/ -type f -ctime -1 -printf 'username@server.xyz.com:%p\\0' |
xargs -0 sh -c 'scp "$@" "$0"' /Users/abcUser/Documents/test/
```